# ASP.NET default button (LinkButton) not working in Google Chrome when multiple defaults exist

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I have an ASP.NET Webforms page that has multiple default buttons throughout. In all browsers ecept Google Chrome they operate as expected but in Chrome the wrong default button fires.

I have read some of the common causes of this problem, eg. invalid HTML (putting Panel inside of TABLE elements) but this is not the case.

I saw one similar question on stackoverflow but there wasn't an accepted answer.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Update:

I read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton%28VS.85%29.aspx) that LinkButtons are not suitable for setting as default buttons.

"Only Button and ImageButton controls are supported."

I guess this must be the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by default button. Also, do you mean to say, you click one button but the event action of other button are called

Comment: i think for my opinion use TabIndex

Comment: Are you putting the buttons inside a asp:panel then setting the defaultbutton property on the panel? Like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx)

Comment: Can you show some of the html side code you've got with these panels and their DefaultButton settings? If it's hefty, comb out the other form elements maybe.

Comment: Yes, I am setting the default button using the Panel tag wrapped around the form.

Comment: I've had same problem in Chrome. I found changing LinkButton to a standard Button solved it. A bit of CSS can make the two look similar.

Comment: Dan - +1, your suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton%28VS.85%29.aspx) that LinkButtons are not suitable for setting as default buttons.

"Only Button and ImageButton controls are supported."

Answer (score 0):

I've never experienced this behavior personally. The DefaultButton property has always worked for me in Chrome, but there is a way around it if you can't really iron it out. You can inject a short JavaScript into the controls that you want to fire buttons for. Here is a non-jQuery method:

```
    StringBuilder script = New StringBuilder("");
    script.Append("if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {");
    script.Append("document.getElementById('" + Me.btnToFire.ClientID);
    script.Append("').click();return false;}} else {return true};");
    this.txtControlToAttach.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", script.ToString());
```

Here is a jQuery solution that can be used to assign multiples in the same block (untested, so it may require tweaking).

```
function fireButtonClick(ctrl, event) {
    if(event.which || event.keyCode){
        if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {
            ctrl.click();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=this.ControlToAttach.ClientID%>").keypress(function(event) {
        fireButtonClick($("#<%=this.btnToFire.ClientID%>"), event);
    });

    $("#<%=this.ControlToAttach2.ClientID%>").keypress(function(event) {
        fireButtonClick($("#<%=this.btnToFire2.ClientID%>"), event);
    });

    // Just keep adding controls here
});
```