# ASP.NET defaultbutton not working in Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, google-chrome

This is a weird one for you...

I have a search box in my web form set up like so:

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlSearch" defaultbutton="btnSearch" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox id="tbSearch" runat="server" />
  <asp:LinkButton id="btnSearch" onClick="EventHandler" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

In FireFox and IE the default button works fine.  In Chrome, however, it doesn't work. Has anyone seen this behavior before and know of a fix? I thought the .NET framework would automatically wire up the correct button when it's set as a defaultbutton on the panel/form...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET default button (LinkButton) not working in Google Chrome when multiple defaults exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135454/asp-net-default-button-linkbutton-not-working-in-google-chrome-when-multiple-d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the defaultButton from a linkButton to a standard button corrected the problem.